# MySQL Union query: PASSING TEMP ClaimID field value to TEMP1 table ClaimID in one union query

Tags: mysql, parameter-passing, union, union-all

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SP_DupAuditCriteria_1`()
BEGIN
    set @RowNbr=concat(date_format(curdate(),'%Y%m%d'),'0000000');

select temp.* from
(SELECT c.*, concat(c.VendorID,a.VendorID) as MergeH200A, concat(a.VendorID,c.VendorID) as MergeH200B, 'New' as Record_Type, @RowNbr:= @RowNbr + 1 AS ClaimID
FROM tbldupaudit_currentitems AS c
    inner join tbldupaudit_archiveitems a 
        on c.InvoiceID = a.InvoiceID
        and c.GrossAmount = a.GrossAmount) as temp
    inner join tbldupaudit_archiveitems b
        on temp.InvoiceID = b.InvoiceID
        and temp.GrossAmount = b.GrossAmount
        and temp.VendorID = b.VendorID
        and temp.VoucherID <> b.VoucherID
Union all
select temp1.* from
(SELECT f.*, concat(f.VendorID,d.VendorID) as MergeH200A, concat(d.VendorID,f.VendorID) as MergeH200B, 'ARCHIVE' as Record_Type, 1 AS ClaimID
FROM tbldupaudit_archiveitems AS f
    inner join tbldupaudit_currentitems d 
        on f.InvoiceID = d.InvoiceID
        and f.GrossAmount = d.GrossAmount) as temp1
    inner join tbldupaudit_currentitems e
        on temp1.InvoiceID = e.InvoiceID
        and temp1.GrossAmount = e.GrossAmount
        and temp1.VendorID = e.VendorID
        and temp1.VoucherID <> e.VoucherID
order by InvoiceID, Record_Type DESC;

END
```

trying make unique ClaimID for each pair. I am able to generate sequential number for first half union all but same ClaimID not able to generate in other half Union all.
Please help me in how to create/generate one unique ID for matched items.

Thank you![image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atBPi.jpg)

Comment: *trying make unique ClaimID for each pair.* What **PAIR**? *for matched items* What is matching criteria?

Comment: What PAIR: Current items vs Archive items, the logic identifies matched items in both current and archive tables. Now I need to give feasibility to tell user that these are in one pair by creating one Unique ID.

Comment: *the logic identifies matched items* WHAT logic? WHAT expression (unique over the dataset) identifies the record and allows to set the records pair matching?

Comment: '''Criteria Same InvoiceID and Same Amount    
Input Tables     
 CurrentItems   ArchiveItems 
 InvoiceID InvoiceID  InvoiceID Amount
 12345 3000  12345 3000
 54321 4560  123456 2000
 12345 3000  12345678 4000
     
Results to be like this     
   ClaimID      InvoiceID InvoiceID  
 UNQ12345 12345 3000  
 UNQ12345 12345 3000 ''' 
this ClaimID should be unique for each PAIR. My apologies if I am not conveying as I am new to MySQL and database world.

Comment: Please add the facts into the question text, not into a comments. With proper formatting.

Comment: Added image please check

Comment: First UNION, then enumerate while sorting by (InvoiceID, FromTable) incrementing only when InvoiceID changed.

Answer (score 0):

In the second select  ( after the UNION ALL) you are  not incrementing a var so if you want both value incrementeedc  the try using a var also for the second

```
select temp.* 
from (
    SELECT c.*, concat(c.VendorID,a.VendorID) as MergeH200A, concat(a.VendorID,c.VendorID) as MergeH200B, 'New' as Record_Type
        , @RowNbr:= @RowNbr + 1 AS ClaimID
    FROM tbldupaudit_currentitems AS c
    inner join tbldupaudit_archiveitems a on c.InvoiceID = a.InvoiceID
        and c.GrossAmount = a.GrossAmount
    ) as temp
inner join tbldupaudit_archiveitems b on temp.InvoiceID = b.InvoiceID
    and temp.GrossAmount = b.GrossAmount
        and temp.VendorID = b.VendorID
            and temp.VoucherID <> b.VoucherID
Union all
select temp1.* 
from ( 
    SELECT f.*, concat(f.VendorID,d.VendorID) as MergeH200A, concat(d.VendorID,f.VendorID) as MergeH200B, 'ARCHIVE' as Record_Type
        , @RowNbr:= @RowNbr + 1 AS ClaimID
    FROM tbldupaudit_archiveitems AS f
    inner join tbldupaudit_currentitems d on f.InvoiceID = d.InvoiceID
        and f.GrossAmount = d.GrossAmount
) as temp1
inner join tbldupaudit_currentitems e on temp1.InvoiceID = e.InvoiceID
      and temp1.GrossAmount = e.GrossAmount
        and temp1.VendorID = e.VendorID
            and temp1.VoucherID <> e.VoucherID
order by InvoiceID, Record_Type DESC;
```

Comment: There are chances of multiple matches from ArchiveItems that time it would be problem I guess..

Comment: The var  .. should return different values ..  so  you should try  ... i guess....

Comment: Tried but results are not as expected in image attached

Comment: ClaimID is added column while running query. you can see there Results table first column is ClaimID.

Answer (score 0):

Modelling example - see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=916b8c26cfed310d2d7dd7e424a6dc17) :

```sql
SELECT CONCAT( 'prefix', LPAD( CASE @prev 
                               WHEN @prev := InvoiceID 
                               THEN @num
                               ELSE @num := @num + 1
                               END, 8, '0' ) ) ClaimID, InvoiceID, Amount, FromTable
FROM ( SELECT InvoiceID, Amount, 'CurrentItems' FromTable
       FROM CurrentItems
       UNION ALL
       SELECT InvoiceID, Amount, 'ArchivedItems'
       FROM ArchivedItems
       WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL 
                      FROM CurrentItems
                      WHERE CurrentItems.InvoiceID = ArchivedItems.InvoiceID) ) unioned,
     ( SELECT @prev := 0, @num := 1000 ) variables
ORDER BY InvoiceID, FromTable DESC;
```